# Why does the direct dispatch version leak under ARC? (and how can I fix that?)

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, selector

I have a section of code that needs to be optimized -- so I have done direct dispatch. The direct dispatch works (as in the code executes, does the right thing and doesn't crash) but ARC somehow loses track of the client object and it never gets deallocated. The standard dispatch version *also* works, and does *not* leak. How can I fix the direct dispatch version?

Standard dispatch version:

```
     Client * client;
     client = [Client newClientForServerSocket: serverSocket];
```

Direct dispatch version:

```
     Client * client;
     Class clientClass = Client.class;
     client = (*IMP_newClientForServerSocket)(clientClass,@selector(newClientForServerSocket:),serverSocket);
```

(Side note: Oddly, if I stick the Client.class directly in the "self" parameter of the dispatch, the dispatch crashes. Could be a clue.)

Answer (score 6):

ARC assumes that a method whose name starts with `new` returns a +1 retain count.

Your `Client *client` variable is `__strong` by default.

In the normal dispatch code, when ARC assigns the reference returned by `newClientForServerSocket:` to `client`, it doesn't adjust the retain count of the `Client` object because it transfers ownership of the +1 returned by `newClientForServerSocket:` to the `client` variable.

In the direct dispatch code, ARC doesn't know that the `IMP_newClientForServerSocket` function returns a +1 retain count. It assumes that the function returns a +0 retain count. So when ARC assigns the reference to the `client` variable, it retains the object. Thus the object is leaked, because the +1 returned by `IMP_newClientForServerSocket` is never released.

You can fix this by telling ARC that `IMP_newClientForServerSocket` returns a +1 retain count. The Clang ARC documentation explains what to do under [“Retained return values”](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#retained-return-values):

> A function or method which returns a retainable object pointer type may be marked as returning a retained value, signifying that the caller expects to take ownership of a +1 retain count. This is done by adding the `ns_returns_retained` attribute to the function or method declaration, like so:
>
> ```
> id foo(void) __attribute((ns_returns_retained));
> - (id) foo __attribute((ns_returns_retained));
> ```
>
> This attribute is part of the type of the function or method.
>
> When returning from such a function or method, ARC retains the value at the point of evaluation of the return statement, before leaving all local scopes.
>
> When receiving a return result from such a function or method, ARC releases the value at the end of the full-expression it is contained within, subject to the usual optimizations for local values.

Here's my test program. Without the `ns_returns_retained` attribute, its memory use grows without bound. With the attribute, its memory use quickly stabilizes.

```
@import Foundation;

@interface Client: NSObject
+ (instancetype _Nonnull)newClient;
@end

@implementation Client
+ (instancetype)newClient { return [self new]; }
@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        typedef Client *(*IMP_newClient_type)(id, SEL) __attribute((ns_returns_retained));
        IMP_newClient_type IMP_newClient = (IMP_newClient_type)[Client methodForSelector:@selector(newClient)];
        while (true) {
            Client *c = IMP_newClient(Client.class, @selector(newClient));
            [c self]; // do something with c to avoid an unused variable warning
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm far from being sure it will work but I would try the following:

```
#import <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
```

and then when you're done with `client`

```
CFRelease((__bridge CFTypeRef)(client));
```

No surprise that ARC doesn't work. It is very unlikely that it was designed to work with allocating objects in such a manner. ARC operates on Objective-C level, not on underlying C stuff